# MySQL Sorting & Indexes For Performance

Tags: mysql

Having some trouble understanding why the an additional sort for a relatively small table is causing such terrible performance. The following query performs wonderfully without u.list_priority in the ORDER BY statement.  The column is indexed.

```
SELECT l.*, u.list_desc
FROM iq_99990022.tbl_vpd_campaign_leads l
INNER JOIN intelliqueue_globalcatalog.tbl_vpd_uploaded_lists u ON l.list_id = u.list_id
WHERE u.campaign_id IN (60238,60241)
AND IFNULL(u.list_state, 'ACTIVE') = 'ACTIVE'
AND l.lead_state = 'READY'
AND l.next_dial_time <= now()
AND l.lead_passes < max_passes
ORDER BY u.list_priority, l.lead_passes ASC
LIMIT 100
```

Here's keys for both tables...

```
u : PRIMARY KEY  (`list_id`),
  KEY `list_priority` (`list_priority`)

l :   PRIMARY KEY  (`lead_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `campaign_id` (`campaign_id`,`lead_phone`,`dupe_key_override`),
  KEY `next_dial_time` (`next_dial_time`),
  KEY `ix_state` (`state`),
  KEY `lead_state` (`lead_state`,`campaign_id`,`lead_passes`)
```

Here's the EXPLAIN results WITHOUT the column in ORDER BY...

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  l   ref next_dial_time,lead_state   lead_state  63  const   15131   Using where; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  u   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   iq_99990022.l.list_id   1   Using where
```

and WITH...

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  l   ref next_dial_time,lead_state   lead_state  63  const   15131   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  u   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   iq_99990022.l.list_id   1   Using where
```

Is it possible that the join across different databases would prevent the index from being used?

Comment: Show us the indexes for **both** tables.

Comment: Added to main question

Comment: An index to `l`.`list_id` for starters.

Comment: added, optimized table and it actually slowed things

Comment: Still wanting an answer on this? Cross-database queries won't have any effect on index usage.